# Why aren't Route-using components (imported from react-router-dom) not translated with react-i18next?

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I am building an app that has a running internationalisation everywhere else but in my Route-using components... here is my i18n.js config file:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    debug: true,
 
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    whitelist: ['en', 'bg'],
 
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, 
    },
 
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },
    react: {
        useSuspense: false,
    },
});

export default i18n;
```

I tried with true useSuspense, false; wait also... The versions of my i18next dependencies are as follows:

```
    "i18next": "^19.5.0",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.1",
    "i18next-sync-fs-backend": "^1.1.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.7.0"
```

This is my call in App.jsx (see below):

```
<Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
```

And this is my index.js file:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Spinner from 'react-bootstrap/Spinner';
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome';
import {faPlusCircle} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from './i18n'

fontawesome.library.add(faPlusCircle);

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}> 
            <Suspense fallback={<Spinner animation="grow" variant="primary" />}>
                <App />
            </Suspense>
        </I18nextProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I am getting this as a console warning:

> i18next.js:22 i18next: hasLoadedNamespace: i18next was not initialized undefined
> output @ i18next.js:22
> i18next.js:22 i18next::translator: key "bg" for languages "en" won't get resolved as namespace "language" was not yet loaded This means something IS WRONG in your setup. You access the t function before i18next.init / i18next.loadNamespace / i18next.changeLanguage was done. Wait for the callback or Promise to resolve before accessing it!!!

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: Where is ` i18n.js` imported and used? We need to see that also.

Comment: @AdamThomas I edited my post with this addition :)

Comment: My guess is that your actual problem is an async one, not that its in the route components. There is a time period where the language files are being downloaded from the server. During that period, you hit the logon screen and it attempts to translate before they are ready.

Comment: Ah but yourn using suspense, which should make it ok. Hmmm. `useSuspense` defo has to be true I think

Comment: Is Login inside of App somewhere presumably?

Comment: Its kind of sucky but you might just wrap your render to wait for them: 
`i18n.on("initialized", () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter>
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}> 
            <Suspense fallback={<Spinner animation="grow" variant="primary" />}>
                <App />
            </Suspense>
        </I18nextProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
})`

Comment: @AdamThomas yes it is.

Comment: Its worth noting its not ideal as your app will block until they are loaded. Whereas with suspense, it will start loading the app then the text would load in parallel. Im not sure why your suspense isnt working, when you tried `useSuspense: true`. That should have been fine.